# How to face alignment and crop?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Usually I recognize a face with dlib, and crop the face with the code:

## Create a face detector

face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

## Run detector and get bounding boxes of the faces on image.

detected_faces = face_detector(image, 1)
face_frames = [(x.left(), x.top(), x.right(), x.bottom()) for x in detected_faces]

return face_frames

It seems simply to recognize face with dlib, but how to align the face in picture?

I saw the code in https://github.com/deepfakes/faceswap, need complex compute.

So how to algin the face and crop it with simple way?

Answer (score 2):

As reported [here](http://dlib.net/face_alignment.py.html) by Davis in the documentation, you can use get_face_chip - if you need a single chip - or get_face_chips - multiple chips. More info [here](http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.get_face_chip) and [here](http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.get_face_chips).

Example 1:

```
images = dlib.get_face_chips(img, faces, size=320)
```

img is the rgb image, faces is a full_object_detections().

Example 2:

```
image = dlib.get_face_chip(img, faces[0])
```

img is the rgb image, faces[0] is the first image get with the shape_predictor.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'get_face_chips'

Comment: windows conda 4.3.30

Comment: What is your dlib version?

Comment: dlib  19.10.0 images = dlib.get_face_chips(img, faces, size=2048, padding=0)